# Problems with apache2 and SSL not load files CSS and JS

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have an application in Ruby on Rails 3.2.8, and I'm using passenger-Nginx as Web Server on port 3037 with Apache2 and SSL using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.  My problem is, when load in chrome or firefox the CSS and JavaScript files do not load.

I have an SSL certificate from Register.com and I have it configured in a VirtualHost this way:

this is in my VirtualHost from port 80

```
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/

    PassengerEnabled off
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3037/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3037/

RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.js|\.css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|css|js)$ - [S=1]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

this is in my file from SSL port 443:

```
        <Proxy *>
            Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/

 ErrorLog /var/www/logs/www.mydomain.com/ssl_error_log.log
 CustomLog /var/www/logs/www.mydomain.com/ssl_access_log.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/mydomain/certs/register/certs_register/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/mydomain/certs/register/shapelovers.key
SSLCACertificateFile /home/mydomain/certs/register/certs_register/Intermediary_Certificate_1.crt

SSLProtocol all
SSLProxyEngine on

    PassengerEnabled off
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3037/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3037/
```

all this in a single file

I've tried everything for can resolve this problem without being able to have exit, if anyone can help me, I'll fully gratefully

**UPDATE**

in web browser Firefox is displayed perfectly without errors, now only the error is displayed in Chrome Browser